# having trouble converting my fetchedresultscontroller var to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to convert this to swift 3

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController = { 
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

but it converts it to this :

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> <<error type>> in 
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

and it gives me errors to put semi colons in random places, how do you declare something like this in swift 3

Comment: Why do you declare `friend` and its `id` as optional although you need it permanently unwrapped in the predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify `ResultType`

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```